# Clarifying Code Review Scope

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I just checked the [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but I'm confused about the working code part.

Quoting from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you have a **working piece of code** from your project and are looking
>   for **open-ended feedback** in the following areas:
>
> - Application of best practices and design pattern usage
> - Potential security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> … then you are in the right place!
>
> ---

Supposed that a website code working on several major browsers but it's not working on a certain major browser.

Is this included in asking for best practice or optimizing code? Or it's fall on looking for debugging /troubleshooting which is not on topic?

Comment: Depends a bit on what exactly you're asking for... If you want the code to be working for that major browser — and that's the only thing that interests you — then the question would be off-topic. If you wanted a review and the thing with the browser is a known (and accepted) defect, it might be okay, because the site works as intended in other browsers... It's probably a bit like C++ code that uses specific compiler directives and only compiles using that specific compiler.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Tbh I'm a bit stumped as to what could I do to optimize the code better. *A bit background*: Previously this code is working well across all major browsers. But after several major browsers updates, the code only remains working well in a certain major browser. Supposed that I was asking about: "Could my code could be optimized so that it works across all major browsers" is that in-scope? Because I'm thinking it could be caused by several major browsers policy/permission changed which aren't logged.

Comment: That does sound a lot like fixing a specific bug. Wouldn't Stack Overflow be the obvious choice here?

Comment: You optimize working code.  You fix broken code.  It sounds like what you need is to fix your code to work with updated browser(s), which would be more appropriate for [SO].  Often times the break is because you code uses undefined or unspecified behavior, and the browser update changed how that works.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for all the feedback. From what I could conclude, only when the code works flawlessly across all related platforms, by then I could ask in Code Review. Otherwise, Stack Overflow is more appropriate for it.

Comment: @Mukyuu "Flawlessly" is a strong word. We do get some optimization questions that want to fix issues with a program "freezing" but eventually returning a correct result. It's not working "flawlessly", but it works. (I have a feeling this doesn't help in understanding our scope better...)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It really depends on your intention writing your question!

*Are you looking to make your code work on other browsers?* If so, you're looking for someone to write a new feature/fix bugs for you, in this case CodeReview isn't the right spot.

*Are you looking to make your existing code better, knowing that it doesn't work in every browser?* That's on-topic, but don't expect someone to "give you the code" to make it work on the other browsers; you'll recieve help on how to make your code better.

The main guideline I would give you is to post your question only if you expect your code will have the same features after the review than it had before. The suggested improvement might make your code faster, more reliable, cleaner, etc. but no new features.

**Also**

Good on you for reading the help center and asking your question on Meta before going on CodeReview, I hope you will be a great contributor here :)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying any confusion I had.